# Is $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ where $ a_1 = -1$ and $a_{n+1} = -(\frac{1}{n^2 + 2} + \frac{\sqrt{10-5a_{n}}}{3})$
Suppose we know already that $a_n$ is convergent. Is $s_n$ convergent?

I would say no because although $a_n$ converges it does not converge to $0$ so the partial sum could be infinite.

Comment: $a_k\to 0$ is a necessary condition for convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Refer also to that [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3009438/505767)

Comment: Do you mean $a_{n+1}=\cdots$ instead of $a_n=\cdots$?

Comment: If $a_n$ converges, then it converges to $\frac{1}{18} \left(\sqrt{385}-5\right)$ so $s_n$ diverges.

Comment: @Raffaele how did you obtain this value of convergence?

Comment: @Outlier if it converges to $x$ then we have $x=\sqrt{10-5x}$ as $\frac{1}{n^2+2}\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

It is true that if $a_n$ converges to some value $L$, then taking limits of both sides of $a_{n+1} = -(\frac{1}{n^2 + 2} + \frac{\sqrt{10-5a_n}}{3})$ as $n\to\infty$ yields $L = -(0+\frac{\sqrt{10-5L}}3)$, which forces $L\ne0$ by regular algebra. In other words, definitely $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $0$. And by the [test for divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test), this automatically means that $\{s_n\}$ diverges.

I wouldn't say "the partial sum could be infinite", though. The manner in which $\{s_n\}$ diverges is not specified by the test for divergence; it could simply oscillate in a bounded fashion without diverging to infinity, for example. Even though "could" makes the statement technically correct, I think it's misleading for those learning about convergence and divergence of series.

Comment: Yes, understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This answer just expands Raffaele's comment.

$a_{n}$ satisfies
$$
-a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n^{2}+2}+\frac{\sqrt{10-5a_{n}}}{3}.
$$
Suppose $a_{n}$ converges to $a$ so that, by taking limits with
respect to $n$ on both sides of the above,
$$
-a=\frac{\sqrt{10-5a}}{3}.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
9a^{2}+5a-10=0. \tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
a=\frac{1}{18}\left(\pm\sqrt{385}-5\right).
$$
In particular, this quantity is nonzero, and hence the series diverges.

*Remark*. If you incorporate the information that $a_1 = -1$, you can preclude the positive root of the quadratic equation (1) above.
However, since [both roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-a%5Bn%2B1%5D+%3D+1%2F%28n%5E2%2B2%29%2BSqrt%5B10-5*a%5Bn%5D%5D%2F3%2C+a%5B1%5D+%3D+-1) of (1) are nonzero, this is not necessary to conclude that the series is divergent.

Comment: Nicely explained!

Comment: @parsiad The negative value must be discarded as $a$ is positive

Comment: @Raffaele: I added some clarification at the end.