# Is this alternating series divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have this series and I need to determine whether it is divergent or convergent, are my calculations correct and it is divergent or am I not seeing something

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \left( \frac{n}{2n+1}\right)^2 
$$
since it is an alternating series I find the limit of  a_n
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \frac{n}{2n+1}\right)^2 = \frac{n^2}{(2n+1)^2} = \frac{n^2}{4n^2+4n+1} = \frac{1}{4}
$$
and since it does not equal to 0 by the alternating divergence test it s divergent ??

Comment: As you say, in order for any series to converge, its terms must go to $0$.  This condition is necessary but sufficient and it has nothing to do with the fact that this series is alternating.

Comment: Yes, this should be correct. The sequence does not converge to 0, so the series can not converge either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a_n \not \to 0$ we can conclude that the series doesn't converges but we don't need to invoque any a*lternating divergence test* since $a_n \to 0$ is a necessary condition for any series to converge, that is

$$\sum_n a_n \quad \text{converges} \implies a_n \to 0$$

therefore

$$a_n \not \to 0 \implies \sum_n a_n \quad \text{doesn't converge}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Limit of infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3009438/505767)

Comment: The alternating test is not applicable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes indeed, we don't need to invoque any other test than the necessary condition. Isn't it clear as I've stated that?

Comment: I mean that the alternating test would not allow you to conclude anything.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes of course, I fully agree! My intention is to say do not consider any other test at all. Necessary condition suffices. Maybe I didn't wrote it in the best way. I can change it if you think in this way it is not sufficently clear. Thanks

Comment: This is just a remark, don't change anything.